# How do I create hyperlinks based on query string value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, hyperlink, query-string

I am creating a website that will have multiple hyperlinks, and I am trying to base the hyperlinks based the query string value. If no query string value is present then I would like the hyperlinks to be defaulted to a specific username, "mhammonds".

Here is the code I have for home.php

```html
<?php  
   
        function username(){
            if(isset($_GET['user'])){
                echo "Your URL is: www.mca.com/?user=" . "$_GET[user]";
                }else {                   
            }
        }
        $USERNAME = username();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>My Site</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe width="480" height="70" src="viral.php"></iframe><br>
        <a href="http://www.tvcmatrix.com/<?php echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ?>">
            Checkout at TVC Matrix</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm not exactly sure where to go next. I'm thinking I would need to add a conditional if/else statement for which hyperlink to be shown, but how do I get the hyperlink to be based off the query string value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try using the ternary operator:  ?: with something like:

```
<a href="http://www.tvcmatrix.com/<?php !empty( $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ? echo $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] else echo 'mhammonds' ?>">
```

The ternary operator is an abbreviated form of if/else.

Comment: Marquell, though this sounds self serving, you might indicate acceptance of my answer so the next person that searches for this see's the resolved answer.

Comment: I would be glad to do that, but I'm not quite sure how. I'm new to stackoverflow and still haven't really become accustomed to how to operate certain things along with how things work.

Comment: Nevermind. Way more simple than I thought.. just click the big check mark by the answer lol

Comment: Nick, is there a way that I can just get the query string value and not the whole query string. I.E. if the query string is user=abelliard, how I do get just abelliard and not user=abelliard?

Comment: You could do something like assign the result of $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] to a variable, then assign the result of explode on & to a variable.  Finally, in a loop, explode that variable on '=' and you'll have the key/value pairs from the query string on each loop iteration. Compare the keys to 'user' to make sure it's there, and that keys value should be 'Abelard'.  Check out the online PHP manual for the explode function.  Also, make sure your tests are specific to what you're looking for.  NEVER make assumptions about data coming in.  That's how you get hacked.